# Determining whether a class implements a generic list in a T4 template

Tags: c#, templates, t4, fxcop

I'm writing a T4 template which loads some classes from an assembly, does some analysis of the classes and then generates some code. One particular bit of analysis I need to do is to determine whether the class implements a generic list. I can do this pretty simply in C#, e.g.

```
public class Foo : List<string> { }

var t = typeof(Foo);

if (t.BaseType != null && t.BaseType.IsGenericType && t.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>)))
    Console.WriteLine("Win");
```

However T4 templates use the FXCop introspection engine and so you do not have access to the .net reflection API. I've spent the past couple of hours in Reflector but still can't figure it out. Does anyone have any clues about how to do this?

Comment: I thought T4 templates were compiled as normal .NET code and executed like normal. Are you saying that "loads some classes from an assembly" is not done the normal way? I would think that doing a normal .NET assembly load would give you full reflection support, wouldn't it?

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.binarycoder.net/fxcop/ as pointed to by the first related question?

Comment: @Lasse Unfortunately t4 templates cannot use the Reflection API because it is optimized for code execution and causes issues with code generation (explained properly in the overview of this blog http://www.olegsych.com/2007/12/how-to-use-t4-to-generate-decorator-classes/)

Comment: Doesn't that just mean that unless you take the necessary steps to load the assemblies into their own appdomain in order to be able to unload them, you shouldn't be using Reflection? It doesn't read (the article that is) to me as *you can't use Reflection in T4*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, it's not very pretty but all type's loaded using AssemblyNode.Load are of type TypeNode, to determine if the type implements List you must do this:

```
node.BaseType.IsGeneric && node.BaseType.Template == FrameworkAssemblies.Mscorlib.Types.SingleOrDefault(t => t.FullName == "System.Collections.Generic.List`1")
```

hope it helps someone!

Comment: Instead of matching by name, you could use FrameworkTypes.GenericList.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded Introspector from http://www.binarycoder.net/fxcop/ (as I mentioned in my comment) and it looks like you need to check BaseType or BaseClass Template.

Comment: Introspector unfortunately didn't give me any more information that Reflector.